# Building a Spring with Maven project's structure

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven

I request assistance with building a Spring with Maven project's structure. I have placed the project's folder hierarchy into:

C:\Documents and Settings...\Documents\workspace-sts-3.6.2.RELEASE\BuildWithMaven\src\main\java\newProject

In that directory, I have a pom.xml with the following contents:

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    org.springframework
    gs-maven
    jar
    0.1.0

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>newProject.HelloWorld</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and two simple classes Greeter.java (the implementation) and HelloWorld.java (the main class).

Where do I put the MANIFEST.MF with the main class indicated?

I have run the mvn compile, mvn package, mvn install commands and have got "no classes to compile" message. I do understand I need a Manifest, but where do I place it and what precisely to indicate there?

Thank you in advance for assistance.

Comment: Your pom.xml is not complete. Your pom shall not be in BuildWithMaven\src\main\java\newProject but in BuildWithMaven.

Comment: It actually posted this way on the forum; in fact, it does have the <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-maven</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
part. The problem must be with the Manifest.

Comment: Could you ten please then put the correct (whole) pom into your question? Please take also int account that pom has to be in project root, not in src/main/java/{package}.

Comment: I do not think you have problem with manifest. You probably have problem with the location of your pom.xml.

Comment: As I indicated in the beginning of my initial post, the pom.xml is in the root directory, newProject in this case. I am asking about where to place the MANIFEST.MF.

Comment: I am also getting a BUILD FAILURE executing the mvn -Barchetype:generate command with the message "No archetype defined. Using maven-archetype-quickstart (org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.0)
". How do I define and archetype for a simple project?

Comment: Your pom is in C:\Documents and Settings...\Documents\workspace-sts-3.6.2.RELEASE\BuildWithMaven\src\main\java\newProject. This is NOT project root. The BuildWithMaven is.

Comment: Do the mvn archteype:generate without -B flag.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for trying to help me! I have solved the problem. The problem was: 1. artifactId is the app name. 2.MANIFEST.MF has to have at least one line which is: Main-Class: src.main.java.hellolanet.HelloPlanet 3. Maven does not create (at least at this point) a MANIFEST. The programmer (surprise!) needs to create it in the resources folder (at the same level as the java folder. After that, issuing the java -jar HelloPlanet-0.1.0.jar command runs the jars' contents. That's all. Here is the output:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
   [INFO]                                                                         
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [INFO] Building HelloPlanet 0.1.0
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [INFO] 
   [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ HelloPlanet ---
   [WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
   [INFO] Copying 1 resource
   [INFO] 
   [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ HelloPlanet ---
   [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
   [INFO] 
   [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @   HelloPlanet ---
   [WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
   [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Documents and Settings\...\Documents\workspace-sts-3.6.2.RELEASE\BuildWithMaven\src\test\resources
   [INFO] 
   [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ HelloPlanet ---
   [INFO] No sources to compile
   [INFO] 
   [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ HelloPlanet ---
   [INFO] No tests to run.
   [INFO] 
   [INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ HelloPlanet ---
   [INFO] 
   [INFO] --- maven-shade-plugin:2.1:shade (default) @ HelloPlanet ---
   [INFO] Replacing original artifact with shaded artifact.
   [INFO] Replacing C:\Documents and Settings\...\Documents\workspace-sts-3.6.2.RELEASE  \BuildWithMaven\target\HelloPlanet-0.1.0.jar with C:\Documents and Settings\...\Documents\workspace-sts-3.6.2.RELEASE\BuildWithMaven\target\HelloPlanet-0.1.0-shaded.jar
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [INFO] Total time: 4.141 s
   [INFO] Finished at: 2014-12-30T11:00:58-05:00
   [INFO] Final Memory: 7M/19M
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------


   C:\Documents and Settings\...\Documents\workspace-sts-3.6.2.RELEASE\Buil
   dWithMaven>mvn package > mvn-package.txt
   C:\Documents and Settings\...\Documents\workspace-sts-3.6.2.RELEASE\Buil
   dWithMaven>cd target

   C:\Documents and Settings\...\Documents\workspace-sts-3.6.2.RELEASE\Buil
   dWithMaven\target>java -jar HelloPlanet-0.1.0.jar > mvn-jar.txt

   C:\Documents and Settings\...\Documents\workspace-sts-3.6.2.RELEASE\Buil
   dWithMaven\target>
   C:\Documents and Settings\...\Documents\workspace-sts-3.6.2.RELEASE\Buil
   dWithMaven>mvn package > mvn-package.txt
   C:\Documents and Settings\...\Documents\workspace-sts-3.6.2.RELEASE\Buil
   dWithMaven>cd target

   C:\Documents and Settings\...\Documents\workspace-sts-3.6.2.RELEASE\Buil
   dWithMaven\target>java -jar HelloPlanet-0.1.0.jar > mvn-jar.txt

   C:\Documents and Settings\...\Documents\workspace-sts-3.6.2.RELEASE\Buil
   dWithMaven\target>
```

Maven is a bit different from Ant. Also, without an Internet connection the shaded jar is not created (surprise!). Now the question is configuring local repositories.